# In Rails, how do I create a link to a new child element when the parent element doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to

I'm building a form to create an exam object that starts with 1 question, and I want to have a button for "New Question" that will AJAX in another question field.

The form works great with only the single question, my problem comes in when I'm trying to create the link to AJAX in another question field.  If I use something like:

```
<%= link_to "New Question", new_exam_question_path(@exam), :remote => true %>
```

rails throws a no route matches error because @exam doesn't actually exist yet. If I replace @exam with Exam.find(10) it will work properly to generate a link for exam 10.

Ideally I'd like to be able to AJAX in as many questions as required.
My single question is being created like below, am I able to re-use that code for the AJAX call:

```
<%= form.fields_for :questions do |f| %>
  <div class="edit_questions">
      <div class="exam_question">
        <%= f.hidden_field :question_type %>
        <%= f.label "Question" %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :copy %>
          <div>
            <% if !f.object.id.blank? %>
              <%= link_to "Delete", exam_question_path(@exam, f.object), :method=>:delete, :class => "button" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you watched [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and its sequel?

Comment: I have not, but will check it out. Thx

Comment: those 2 railscasts were priceless and I've got it all working now. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamEberlin, moved my answer to the proper spot, I didn't have enough credit on SO to answer my own question right away so I just put it in the question so others wouldn't waste their time.  Thx for the tip tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: rails casts 196 and 197 give you all the background required to solve my problem.

this is definitely not the simplest of fixes, but these rails casts were very similar to what I'm trying to do so I could follow very closely. Following the naming conventions shown in the cast is important as there are dynamically built during the process and it will break if you don't follow the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just instantiate an empty exam object in the controller before rendering the view?

```
@exam = Exam.new
```

Comment: That is already happening in the "new" method but the view still fails presumably because there is no id on the pool to link to.